# Добавление библиотек в сборку Gulp4

Tags: javascript, gulp

https://github.com/edisleka/bootstrap4-gulp-starter.git

Подскажите как в этот проект добавить другие библиотеки к примеру owl-carousel.js, она имеет js и css файлы.